# Can't over ride CSS text style and images shifting down?

Tags: css, image, text, styles

My test site is at: http://www.stagecraft.org/msi/

On the third "page" (Portfolio) I have three images that flip around and show text on the "back".  I have two problems:

- I can't get the text where the architect, owner, and GC are listed to change.  I have tried creating a class of `.spinbody` but when I apply it, the text doesn't change.  I need a different text styling/size here.
- The images aren't fitting their rectangular regions exactly.  They seem to be shifted "down" a bit.  The images are `300px x 500px` and the regions are as well.  But the images are offset from the regions.

Any ideas where my mistakes are?  I am pretty much a novice and have been piecing this code together.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What style are you trying to aply to this text? There are already
   css rules that style it and you may have some CSS overrides that
   block your changes. You could add `!important` at the end of your
   new rules but it isn't the best solution. The best solution would be
   to inspect your CSS with some browser developper tools (ex: firebug
   for firefox) and see how you can itegrate your new CSS rules to the
   existing code.
2. For the second problem, there is a `top-margin` aplied to the images
   so they are shifted down. the margin is aplied on `#section1 img`
   line 173 of `msi_style.css` you could delete it but be sure it
   won't change the other images too.

**EDIT**

The text size on the back of the flip card comes from `.intro p` on line 190 of `msi_style.css`

Comment: OK.  The top-margin was the problem!  For the text, I just want to make the non-header text on the back of the "cards" smaller.  But I'm not sure where that text is pulling it's sty;le from in the CSS.

Comment: @Steve The text size on the back of the flip card comes from `.intro p` on line 190 of `msi_style.css` (see my edit)

Comment: Aha.  I see that when I change that I also change the body type of most of the other "pages".  I really just want to decrease the text on the "cards" to 1em rather than the 1.5em of .introp.  Any suggestion on best practices to do that?

Comment: @Steve add this to your css : .intro .flip p{font-size:1em;}

Comment: remove the dot before the p in your stylesheet and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check on to the firebug where exactly your css rules collapsing and try to make your this rule more specific using element and id combination...
Or for time being you can fix it by using !important at the end of your new rules but it isn't the best solution....